# SQL Unique constraint allowing different capitalizations

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

We have a UNIQUE constraint on a varchar field in our SQL table. But would like it to allow variations in Capitalization. So, `MoneyBelt` and `moneyBelt` would be allowed as Unique values. Is this possible?

Comment: This depends on the collation of the column.  You would appear to have a case insensitive collation.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: So @GordonLinoff I would need to add a collation to the column definition, not change the constraint?

Comment: @MKenyonII . . . You could also add a computed column and then build a unique index on that.

Comment: @MKenyonII you would need to change the coalition, a simple ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN statement will get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. This led me to the answer.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Somedata] ALTER COLUMN ItemName
    varchar(30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS NOT NULL
GO
```

This allows for the constraint to be case sensitive. Notice the `CS` portion of `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS`.